# how to take applications off of vm for local machine

Tags: virtual-machines, application, safe-remove

I have a virtual machine that we are going to do away with, but it has applications on it that we'd like to keep.

Is it possible to take those applications off of that vm and place them on my local machine?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What would you be doing if this was physical hardware that was going away with applications on it?  Follow that process.

Comment: You know, I'd call this a real question. Just because it betrays a fair amount of ignorance, that level of misunderstanding is still pretty common with virtualization technology, so I think we should take the opportunity to continue to correct folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what MDPC said. The fact that it's a VM doesn't change at all how you manage the applications that are installed into the OS of it.

So yeah - for each application, read up on how to backup and restore it to a new machine, and then do that.